# Can the default preferred size for a JScrollPane containing a JTree be removed?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

When I add a JScrollPane containing a JTree to a JPanel with a GridBagLayout, it behaves as if it had a fixed size. If you run the following code example, note that the content panel has a vertical scroll bar eventhough the JTree is quite small. Also note that the `spForTree.getPreferredSize()` is returning a set size even though my code has not set it (and I don't want to set a size).

My question: is there any way to avoid the scrollbar when the tree is small? I've tried a few things:

1. I tried explicitly calling `spForTree.setPreferredSize(null)` to clear the preferred size.  This had no effect.  Subsequent call to `getPreferredSize()` still returns `Dimension(123,363)`.
2. I tried explicitly calling `spForTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100))` to set a smaller size. This works, but I don't want a fixed size. I need the preferred size to be removed so that the scroll pane just uses the available space.
3. I tried extending `JScrollPane` and overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method to always return `null`. This resulted in a NullPointerException at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:1118)

Here's sample code that demonstrates this issue:

```
package tree.test;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class TreeTEST {
  public TreeTEST() {
    super();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel m_contentPanel = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane spForContent = new JScrollPane(m_contentPanel);
    spForContent.setBorder(null);
    m_contentPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(spForContent) ;

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    JScrollPane spForTree = new JScrollPane(tree);
    boolean ispref = spForTree.isPreferredSizeSet(); 
    Dimension dim1 = spForTree.getPreferredSize();
    System.out.println("isPreferredSizeSet = " +ispref +" dim y = " +dim1.height);

    m_contentPanel.add(spForTree, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, 
                                                         GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    frame.pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TreeTEST ttest = new TreeTEST();      
 }      
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the Frame created by the sample code:

[image: Frame created by sample code]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I want the JTree and its scroll pane to expand to its largest possible size without causing scrollbars on the outer scroll pane"* Take a moment and read that out loud, because it's counterintuitive

Comment: Thanks. That statement is not counterintuitive. The inner scroll pane should as large as possible without causing scrollbars on the outer scroll pane.  Look at the screen shot image.  See that the inner scroll pane is larger that the window so that it is causing scroll bars on the outer scroll pane EVENTHOUGH the contents of the inner scroll pane are quite small.

Comment: Please see the complete example that I added above.  Thanks.

Comment: An MCVE should be completely self contained, so should include imports and the bits needed to turn it into a class (containing the `main` method). OTOH that is so close to being an MCVE, I'll add a vote to reopen.

Comment: And a Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: I was hoping this issue would be reopened.  If you try my latest sample program, it clearly demonstrates that the JScrollPane for a JTree has always has a preferred size, which is treated as a fixed size when using a GridbagLayout.   I really need help to figure out how to make this sizing more dynamic, based on the size available in the Gridbag.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.